# Cucumber+Java: A step Regex definition breaks association with @ParameterType

Tags: java, regex, cucumber

I use *Cucumber* to test the code in my *Java* project, all is developed and ran in *IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.4 (Ultimate Edition)*.

Originaly, my test was defined using *Cucumber expressions* and worked fine with `@ParameterType`:

```
@When("The {tester} does whatever")
public void testWhatever(Tester t) {
    ...
}

@ParameterType("abc|def|hgi")
public Tester tester(String testerName) {
    return Tester.valueOf(testerName);
}
```

The test in this form works perfectly.

Then further developing the test I had to switch the test definition to *Regex*, and the test definition took the following form:

```
@When("^The (?'tester'abc|def|hgi) does whatever$")
public void testWhatever(Tester t) {
    ...
}
```

Now the test does not work failing in runtime to convert the captured string to the required type.

The relevant nested exceptions in this case are:

`Caused by: io.cucumber.cucumberexpressions.CucumberExpressionException: ParameterType {anonymous} failed to transform [abc] to interface com.acme.Tester`

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't transform 'abc' to interface com.acme.Tester BuiltInParameterTransformer only support a limited number of class types Consider using a different object mapper or register a parameter type for interface com.acme.Tester`

It seems that the association of my custom `ParameterType` with the data, which worked in *Cucumber expression* via `{tester}`, is broken in *Regex*.

I have no more ideas what to try in order to make it work.

I shall deeply appreciate any assistance from you guys.

Answer (score 0):

To match a regex with a parameter type, the regex must match that of the parameter type. For example:

```java
@When("^The (abc|def|hgi) does whatever$")
public void testWhatever(Tester t) {
    ...
}

@ParameterType("abc|def|hgi")
public Tester tester(String testerName) {
    return Tester.valueOf(testerName);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer.
If you look at my sample code, you will see that `@ParameterType` is defined exactly as the step.
`(?'tester'abc|def|hgi)` is a Regex notation for **named** capturing group (name is not the part of a matching pattern), which I tried after simple capturing group `(abc|def|hgi)` did not work.

Comment: The regex `(abc|def|hgi)` and `(?'tester'abc|def|hgi)` may match the same inputs, they're not the same regex. Also a named regex uses `<` and `>` to delimit the name, rather than `'` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html.